# CodeIgniter htaccess remove query string from URL

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have would like to change the url 
**mysite.com/page?id=s3q4afas** 
to 
**mysite.com/page/s3q4afas** with htaccess.

What I have until now:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [PT,L]


RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}page/%1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: You skipped [the URL section of the docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html).  You don't need to mess with `.htaccess` for this!  **By default, query strings are disabled in CodeIgniter.**  Just make sure that CodeIgniter's `enable_query_strings` configuration option is set to `FALSE`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>


    RewriteEngine on
    ##1)Redirect "/page/?id=foo" to "/page/foo"##
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page/?\?id=([^\s]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /page/%1? [L,R]
    ##2)internally redirect "/page/foo" to "/page/?id=foo"##
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ /page/?id=$1 [NC,L]
    ##3)rewrite any other non-existent request to "index.php"##
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Maybe after `page` slash should be avoided because there is no any in his example. Or is that already made by these codes `/page/?\?id=([^\s]+)` and `/page/?id=$1`?

Comment: Why use `.htaccess` for this when a simple CodeIgniter configuration option determines the URL format?   (**By default**, query strings are disabled in CodeIgniter.)

Comment: Works perfectly, but now I get the 404 page. :-( I do not like enable the query strings per default!

Answer (score 0):

You would not need to alter the `.htaccess` file for this.  CodeIgniter's URLs are segmented by default, unless you've intentionally set the `enable_query_strings` configuration option to `TRUE`.

> **By default**, URLs in CodeIgniter are designed to be search-engine and human friendly. Rather than using the standard “query string” approach to URLs that is synonymous with dynamic systems, **CodeIgniter uses a segment-based approach**:

```
example.com/news/article/my_article
```

SEE:  [codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)

> **Enabling Query Strings**
>
> In some cases you might prefer to use query strings URLs:

```
index.php?c=products&m=view&id=345
```

> CodeIgniter ***optionally*** supports this capability, which can be enabled in your `application/config.php` file. If you open your config file you’ll see these items:

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
```

> If you change `enable_query_strings` to `TRUE` this feature will become active. Your controllers and functions will then be accessible using the “trigger” words you’ve set to invoke your controllers and methods:

```
index.php?c=controller&m=method
```